# two person chat room

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been trying for two days to get this to work. It's a two person chat room: user1 and user2 can enter into room1. No one could enter the room1 unless they are either user1 or user2.

as of now, its only showing room1 for user1, but when I use user2 from another browser, it doesn't show room1 unless I do user1. I want both users to see room1. This is my SQL SELECT:

Sorry, I'm a newbie with MySQL, but basically I created a login page where user1 and user2 can enter their user names. Once they're are logged in, it will show the room1 information.

```
$sql = "SELECT room FROM chat WHERE user1='$user1' AND user2='$user2' and room='$room1'";

$result = $conn->query($sql); 
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
  $_SESSION['room'] =$row['room'];
 } 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That would be a weird table schema. Would you mind to elaborate your chat room database schema?

Comment: We're going to need more code than just some SQL query for this. Also, have you thought about moving the allowed users to a separate table? What happens when in the future you want to allow 3 users to join a chat? or 16? You have to keep adding columns to your table?

Comment: @Mike thanks for your suggestion, I only needed for two person. I just need both users to see the room content or name pulled from room column.

Comment: You do realize that code in comments loses all the line breaks, syntax highlighting and formatting, right? Try editing your question instead.

Comment: And you only need it for 2 people *now*. What about 6 months from now when you want to have the ability to have more than 2 people in a room?

Comment: Thanks Mike, didn't know I could re-edit my question! It's a very simple coding and I am not really advanced yet so I will settle for two person per room.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not provided much information about your requirement,I am assuming that you what to create a chat room for two users and these two users can only participate in this room.For this you should not user this schema.

> You need to create different tables of different entities and there
>   relationship.

Here you have two entities.

1. User
2. room

And one relation between them.

1. Chat room

### room_table(Insert when room is created)

```
        id          -room id
        name        -room name
        created_at  -time of creation
        status      -is this room is active or not
        etc
```

### user_table(Insert when user created)

```
        id          -user id
        name        -user name
        password    -password
        created_at  -time of creation
        status      -is this user is active or not
        etc
```

### chat_room(Insert when user is assigned in room)

```
        id          -user id
        room_id     -room_id//reference of room.id
        user1_id    -user_id//reference of user.id
        user2_id    -user_id//reference of user.id
        created_at  -time of creation
        status      -is this chat room is active or not
        etc
```

now for any user you to get the chat_room by:

```
 select id from chat_room where room_id = '$room_id' and user1_id ='$user_id' or user2_id ='$user_id';
```

Hope this will help you and other. I am wrong any where any one correct   me.

### Edit:

### messages(Insert when sending message)

```
        id              -user id
        chat_room_id    -id of chat room//reference of chat_room.id
        user_id         -user_id//reference of user.id
        message_text         -text message
        created_at      -time of creation
        status          -is this chat room is active or not
        etc
```

Now for any chat room you can get messages by :

```
select message_text from messages where chat_room_id = 'id_you_got_from_above_query';
```

Comment: You probably want to have `$user1_id` and `$user_2_id` in your SQL since they will be different user ids.

Comment: yes but here we are selecting the chat room for any user and then we can fetch other information related to this chat room like messages and all. correct if i am wrong.

Comment: Thanks Anand, I am trying to work off this coding from this tutorial [link](https://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/) and all their chat log are saved in a text file. So when my users1 and user2 log into the chat room, it will pull a text file like "room1.txt"  chat log.

Comment: ok then you can save the room1 in database as room name and after selecting chat_room for any user you can get the room_name from room_id and then you can fetch the the chat from that file.

Comment: as you are new i suggest you use the database for storing the chats.. it would be much easy.

Comment: I know what you mean, I thought about that too but I like for now to save it as a text file, because its only a one time conversation between two persons before an other new users come along. I am trying to work out your suggestions, can show me the query how I would do that if I create another table for room?

Comment: few min i will edit this.. and if this answer is correct accept this as appreciation ;)